# WordPress: How to create a rewrite rule for a file in a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been looking for hours trying to find a straightforward answer to this but I just can't seem to find anything out there which tackles this issue. There are numerous examples for rewriting standard URLs, but nothing in-terms of rewriting pages from within a custom plugin.

I've created a custom plugin with a special directory in it called `test`. The test directory has several pages which are `blah.php` and `shmeh.php`. Is it possible to create rewrite rules to these pages i.e. http://example.com/blah, http://example.com/shmeh

Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So essentially what you are looking for, is to have Wordpress load a specific page template (`blah.php`) when the user visits `http://example.com/blah/`. Also, you need it to to be completely generated in your plug-in without actually creating any pages or posts. You are on the right track. What you want to do here is create a rewrite rule that utilizes a specific query var to load the page. Here it is step by step:

**Step 1: Rewrite rules**

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule*

```
/* Rewrite Rules */
add_action('init', 'yourpluginname_rewrite_rules');
function yourpluginname_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'blah/?$', 'index.php?blah=true', 'top' );
}
```

So in the above code, your just telling Wordpress that `example.com/blah/` should be treated as if the user were visiting `example.com/index.php?blah=true`. Now "blah" is a query var that you will set up in the next function below. Query vars are just what Wordpress calls $_GET variables. However they must be registered with Wordpress so it can properly store the value (which is "true" in this case). We will do that below in the next function. It's also worth noting the third setting in the function `"top"`, which gives this rewrite rule priority over other rewrite rules. Alternatively, setting it to "bottom" would check that no other rewrite rules match first before using this one.

**Step 2: Query Vars**

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars*

```
/* Query Vars */
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'yourpluginname_register_query_var' );
function yourpluginname_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'blah';
    return $vars;
}
```

In the code above, your just registering the query var "`blah`" with Wordpress. That way, when someone visits `example.com/blah/`, which your rewrite rule tells Wordpress to treat it like they are visiting `example.com/index.php?blah=true`, Wordpress actually bothers to save it's value (which is set to `true`). This is so you can use it in the next function, which loads the template you want when users visit your url.

**Step 3: Template Include**

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path*

```
/* Template Include */
add_filter('template_include', 'yourpluginname_blah_template_include', 1, 1); 
function yourpluginname_blah_template_include($template)
{
    global $wp_query; //Load $wp_query object
    $page_value = $wp_query->query_vars['blah']; //Check for query var "blah"

    if ($page_value && $page_value == "true") { //Verify "blah" exists and value is "true".
        return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'test/blah.php'; //Load your template or file
    }

    return $template; //Load normal template when $page_value != "true" as a fallback
}
```

In the code above, you are simply telling Wordpress to use your `blah.php` template any time the query var "`blah`" is present and set to `true`. In this case it is present because a user is visiting a url with a rewrite rule that utilizes the "`blah`" query var. The function checks if the "`blah`" query var is present, then checks if "`blah`" is set to true, and if so loads the template. Also note that the template path is `test/blah.php`. You are using `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)` to relatively include the template based on the location of your plugin. That way it's relative as a plug-in should be.

**Step 4: The Actual Template (blah.php)**

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer*

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar*

Your template file will need to load the header, footer, and sidebar itself. When using `template_include`, Wordpress will not automatically load the header and footer as if you were using a page template. Be sure your template file calls `get_header()`, `get_footer()`, and `get_sidebar()` so that you get your complete layout.

**Notes**

Hope this helps, I was searching for something similar the other day and had to figure it out the hard way. It's also worth noting that I have prefixed all of the functions as "yourpluginname_". You can change this to whatever you want your prefix to be, but be sure to update the function names to match as well.

Comment: Mate, you're a legend! Thank you very very much for the help! Not to mention the absolutely highly detailed answer, I was expecting more of a point in the right direction and a kick in the ass haha

Comment: You're welcome. I've saved countless hours by finding solutions on here, so I like to pay it forward.

Comment: @Mastrianni I have used same as you mentioned above but I am getting Notice: Undefined index: blah .. can you please give me any suggestion to short out this .

Comment: @NipunTyagi Does `test/blah.php` exist in your plugin directory? I have a feeling you missed something when copying/modifying the code.

Comment: @Mastrianni Hi Mate, yes its working for me as well, But I have another question for you if you don't mind..:) Actually I've placed a link on post page to show all comments, on this new page I have to show all comments from that post, how can I pass the post id on this new page? As you set 'index.php?blah=true' how can I set post id instead of true in it so I can get that id on my new page ?

Comment: Awesome answer this explains everything I wanted to know about the problem I was unsure how to tackle, ever works nicely with the theme wrapper I made as I am not using this in a plugin but a theme for a custom archive URL structure.